# Test NFC android Read only 12 sector

Tags: android, nfc

I try to write a program to read all the sector of NCF tag.So when I run the test :

- the tag is detected
- I get the tag Id
- I get the number of sector

But i can only read the first sector !

Here my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String TAG_LOCAL = "Home - ";
    public boolean MODE_DEBUG_LOCAL = true;
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter[] intentFilter;
    String[][] generalTechLists;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.w("ISI", "Main Start");

        //detect if NFC device
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
            Log.w("ISI", "NFC detected");
        }else{
            Log.w("ISI", "NFC NOT detected");
        }




        IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndef.addDataType("*/*");
        } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            Log.w("ISI", " error ndef = " + e.getMessage());
        }
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter[] {ndef};

        generalTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { MifareClassic.class.getName() } };

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }

    void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            //Identifiant du tag NFC
            byte[] byte_id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
            Log.w("ISI", "Tag id = " + ByteArrayToHexString(byte_id));

            //techno disponible
            Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            String[] techList = tagFromIntent.getTechList();
            for (int Cpt = 0; Cpt <techList.length; Cpt++){
                Log.w("ISI", "Techno = " + techList[Cpt]);
            }


            //QUESTION A POSER DANS XDA!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent);
            try{
                mfc.connect();
                int size = mfc.getSize();
                Log.w("ISI", "size (byte) = " + size);
                int nbrSector = mfc.getSectorCount();
                Log.w("ISI", "NbrSector = " + nbrSector);
                for (int Cpt = 0; Cpt < nbrSector; Cpt++){
                    boolean auth = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(Cpt, MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT);
                    if (auth){


                        int nbrBlock = mfc.getBlockCountInSector(Cpt);
                        Log.w("ISI", "NbrBlock = " + nbrBlock + " for sector " + Cpt);
                        for (int k = 0; k < nbrBlock; k++){
                            byte[] data = mfc.readBlock(k);
                            Log.w("ISI", "Block num " + k + " - data " + ByteArrayToHexString(data));
                        }

                    }else{
                        Log.w("ISI", " Impossible to connect at sector " + Cpt);
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.w("ISI", " error = " + e.getMessage());
            }


        }// End of method
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilter, generalTechLists);
    }


    private String getHexString(String hex){

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
            String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
            output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }
        return output.toString();
    }


    String ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] inarray) {
        //Thanks Adam Laurie sur XDA
        int i, j, in;
        String [] hex = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
        String out= "";

        for(j = 0 ; j < inarray.length ; ++j) {
            in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
            i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
            i = in & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
        }
        return out;
    }

}
```

And here the log :

```
Tag id = C44F0EDD
Techno = android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic
Techno = android.nfc.tech.NfcA
Techno = android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable
size (byte) = 1024
NbrSector = 16
NbrBlock = 4 for sector 0
Block num 0 - data C44F0EDD58880400C185149849803612
Block num 1 - data 00000000000000000000000000000000
Block num 2 - data 00000000000000000000000000000000
Block num 3 - data 000000000000FF078069FFFFFFFFFFFF
NbrBlock = 4 for sector 1
error = Tag was lost.
```

So I don't understand what happens.

Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```java
for (int k = 0; k < nbrBlock; k++){
  byte[] data = mfc.readBlock(k);
  Log.w("ISI", "Block num " + k + " - data " + ByteArrayToHexString(data));
}
```

with this

```java
byte[] data = mfc.readBlock(bIndex);
for (int k = 0; k < nbrBlock; k++){
  bIndex = mfc.sectorToBlock(Cpt);
  bIndex++;
  Log.w("ISI", "Block num " + k + " - data " + ByteArrayToHexString(data));
}
```

from: http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.it/

Answer (score 0):

**Set your code like this:**

```
int bIndex = 0;
try{
    mfc.connect();
    int size = mfc.getSize();
    Log.i("ISI", "size (byte) = " + size);
    int sectorCount = mfc.getSectorCount();
    Log.i("ISI", "NbrSector = " + sectorCount);
    for (int Cpt = 0; Cpt < sectorCount; Cpt++){
        boolean auth = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(Cpt, MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT);
        if (auth){
            int nbrBlock = mfc.getBlockCountInSector(Cpt);
            Log.i("ISI", "NbrBlock = " + nbrBlock + " for sector " + Cpt);
            for (int k = 0; k < nbrBlock; k++){
                byte[] data = mfc.readBlock(bIndex);
                Log.i("ISI", "Block num " + k + " - data " + ByteArrayToHexString(data));
                bIndex++;
            }
        }else{
            Log.i("ISI", " Impossible to connect at sector " + Cpt);
        }
   }
 }catch(IOException e){
     Log.i("ISI", " error = " + e.getMessage());
 }
```